# Accessing a Dynamic Array causing a runtime error

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

I've been messing around with dynamic memory and I've hit a huge wall.

I'm trying to create a program where the user enters as many strings as they want, then can quit whenever, however after a second string is entered, the program crashes with out giving me any specific error message.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "new"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Variables
    int i=0,end=0,requiresSize=1;
    char ** temp;
    char  item[256]="a";
    char ** requires;


    //Initialize each element in requiers
    requires = new char * [requiresSize];
    for(int j=0;j<requiresSize*2;j++){
        requires[j]= new char[256];
    }


    while(strcmp(item,"q-")){
        end=0;
        printf("Enter h- for help.\nEnter q- to quit.\n");
        printf("Please enter a string\n");
        gets_s(item);
        if(!strcmp(item,"h-")){
            printf("Enter a string to add to the list.\nEnter p- to print the list.\n");
            end=1;
        }   
        if(!strcmp(item,"q-")){
            break;
        }
        if(!strcmp(item,"p-")){
            if(requires[0]!=NULL){
                for(int j=0;j<requiresSize;j++){
                    printf("%d. %s\n",j,requires[j]);
                }
            }
            end=1;
        }
        while(end==0){
                printf("check1:i=%d\n",i);
            //if search index is larger than size of the array,reallocate the array
            if(i>= requiresSize){
                temp = new char * [requiresSize*2];
                //Initialize each element in temp
                printf("check2:temp initalized\n");
                for(int j=0;j<requiresSize*2;j++){
                    temp[j]= new char[256];
                }
                printf("check3:temp itmes initialized\n");
                for(int j =0;j<requiresSize;j++){
                    //for each element in requires, copy that element to temp
                    temp[j]=requires[j];
                }
                printf("check4:copied requires into temp\n");
                delete * requires;
                requires = temp;
                printf("check5:deleted requires and set requires equal to temp\n");
                delete  temp;
                requiresSize = requiresSize *2;         
            }
                printf("check6:\n");
            //if the index at requires is not empty, check to see if it is the same as given item
            if(requires[i]!= NULL){
                printf("check8:index at requires is not empty\n");
                //I know the error occurs here, something to do with accessing requires[i]
                if(!strcmp( item,  requires[i])){
                printf("check9:index at requires is the same as item\n");
                    //if they are the same, break out of the loop, item is already included
                    break;
                }else{
                printf("check10:index at requires is different\n");
                    //otherwise, increase the index and check again (continue loop)
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
            }else{
                printf("check11:index at requires is null, item added\n");
                //if the index is empty, add the item to the list and break out of loop
                requires[i]=  item;
                break;
            }
                printf("check7\n");

        }
    }
    delete requires;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use std::string - your code is basically C with new replacing malloc.

Comment: by the way your first `for` loop already accesses the array you allocate past its bounds and invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: The presence of `#include "stdafx.h"` suggests you are using Visual Studio. Visual Studio has one of best debuggers on the market, if not the best. I recommend taking advantage of it to step through the code with an eye out for where the program starts deviating from the expected.

Comment: *I'm trying to create a program where the user enters as many strings as they want* -- `std::vector<std::string>`.  All of that code you wrote is replaced by that.

Comment: [Example](http://ideone.com/ihAjMg).  Compare that with what you're trying to do.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie, I've worked with vectors before, but I am specifically trying to work with and get a handle on dynamic arrays

Comment: @Chaospyke Then in a structured way, create your own vector and string class and then use that in your code.  You really don't learn anything doing spaghetti-like logic using `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that an assignment statement such as `temp = requires` (in this case) is only copying over the pointer, so that `temp` is now pointing to the same location in memory as `requires`; it does NOT copy over that memory.

This is leading to two problems:

1. You are allocating new 256-char arrays to each element of `temp`, and then reassigning each char* in `temp` to point to a different location, leaking all of that memory; there is now no way to reference the newly-allocated memory, and thus no way for you to free it.
2. You are assigning the pointer `temp` to `requires`, which, again, just means the two are now pointed to the same location in memory, and then deleting `temp`, which frees that memory (that, again, `requires` is also now pointing to).

Also, if you use `new[]` to allocate an array, you must use `delete[]` to free it. So `requires = new char * [requiresSize];` requires you to use `delete [] requires;` at the end of the program, instead of just `delete requires;`. Same for each 256-char element of `requires`.

So, replace `temp[j]=requires[j];` with an appropriate call to strcpy (or strncpy). And do not delete `temp`; the `delete [] requires;` at the end will handle that, since it is now pointing to that bit of memory.

Comment: How will the array reallocate then? If I reallocate temp (or the memory its pointing to) with new while its holding data, won't that overwrite the previous data?

Comment: No. `temp` is merely a pointer; it's value is the location in memory it points to. When you assign a new value to it, either by copying some other pointer's value to it, or assigning it the result of new/new[], it does not affect the memory originally pointed to by `temp`. Again, a statement like `requires = temp;` merely makes the two pointers point to the same area of memory (the memory originally pointed to by `temp`; it does not free any memory.

Comment: Then how do i expand the allocated memory pointed to by temp?

Comment: You'll do what you're doing now: allocate new memory to `temp`, copy over the pointers from `required`, free `required`, at which point `temp` is fine for you to use again the next time.

Comment: I commented out    ` delete temp;` and that seems to have everything working properly. Perhaps you could help me figure out why when I try to access the data in the array, I get random symbols. I figured that it might not be worth a separate question.